# how to fill up a select with the options of another select

Tags: jquery

How I can fill up my select #2 with the option value of select #1 using jquery?

For example select #1 is:

```
<select id="#1">
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
```

My select #2 should be like this:

```
      <select id="#2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: `id` shouldn't contain `#` if am not wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Fiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/n5g4td0k/)**

If you change it to proper `id` as I've done below, you can get it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#2").append($('#1').html()); //set options of 2nd select from options of 1st select
   $("#2 option").each(function(){
       $(this).text($(this).val());//set its text based on its value
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="1">
    <option value="1">Val 1</option>
    <option value="2">Val 2</option>
    <option value="3">Val 3</option>
</select>
<select id="2">
</select>
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. Do not forget to mark it as answer.. :)

Comment: The `id` attribute, starting with a number, is **only** permitted in HTML5 document. Keep in mind that you must use `<!doctype html>` in very beginning of your file(s)

Comment: GonzalezZoe.. Please make a note of @bodi0's comment... You can get to know more about it from **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)**.. Thank you bodi0 for information..